# Getting rid of a warning in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio seems to think `SparseArray` values cannot be `null`.

When I write

```
public static void foo() {
    SparseArray<Object> sparseArray = new SparseArray<Object>();
    sparseArray.put(0, null);
    if (sparseArray.valueAt(0) == null)
        Log.d("MyClass", "Hello World");
}
```

I get the warning

> condition 'sparseArray.valueAt(0) == null' is always 'false'

I'd just like to know what annotation or comment I need to put to get rid of the warning. I don't want to disable inspections, just get rid of this particular warning. Thanks.

Comment: This indeed looks like a Lint issue as I checked SparseArray's sources and null should be pretty valid value. You should consider filling a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Thanks, I will do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can suppress inspections locally with `//noinspection <inspectionname>`.

For example:

```
//noinspection ConstantConditions
if (sparseArray.valueAt(0) == null)
```

gets rid of this false warning.